# OpenMP Strange Behavior - differences in performance

Tags: c++, openmp

I want to speedup image processing code using OpenMP and I found some strange behavior in my code. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I also tried Intel C++ compiler with same result.
I'm not sure why is the code with OpenMP in some situations much slower than in the others. For example function `divideImageDataWithParam()` or difference between `copyFirstPixelOnRow()` and `copyFirstPixelOnRowUsingTSize()` using `struct TSize` as parameter of image data size. Why is performance of `boxFilterRow()` and `boxFilterRow_OpenMP()` so different a why isn't it with different radius size in program?

I created github repository for this little testing project:
https://github.com/Tb45/OpenMP-Strange-Behavior

Here are all results summarized:
https://github.com/Tb45/OpenMP-Strange-Behavior/blob/master/resuts.txt

I didn't find any explanation why is this happening or what am I doing wrong.
Thanks for your help.

I'm working on faster box filter and others for image processing algorithms.

```
typedef intptr_t int_t;

struct TSize
{
    int_t width;
    int_t height;
};



void divideImageDataWithParam(
    const unsigned char * src, int_t srcStep, unsigned char * dst, int_t dstStep, TSize size, int_t param)
{
    for (int_t y = 0; y < size.height; y++)
    {
        for (int_t x = 0; x < size.width; x++)
        {
            dst[y*dstStep + x] = src[y*srcStep + x]/param;
        }
    }
}


void divideImageDataWithParam_OpenMP(
    const unsigned char * src, int_t srcStep, unsigned char * dst, int_t dstStep, TSize size, int_t param, bool parallel)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for if(parallel)
    for (int_t y = 0; y < size.height; y++)
    {
        for (int_t x = 0; x < size.width; x++)
        {
            dst[y*dstStep + x] = src[y*srcStep + x]/param;
        }
    }
}
```

Results of divideImageDataWithParam():

```
generateRandomImageData :: 3840x2160
numberOfIterations = 100
```

With Visual C++ 2019:

```
      32bit       64bit
     336.906ms   344.251ms   divideImageDataWithParam
    1832.120ms  6395.861ms   divideImageDataWithParam_OpenMP single-thread parallel=false    
     387.152ms  1204.302ms   divideImageDataWithParam_OpenMP multi-threaded parallel=true
```

With Intel C++ 19:

```
  32bit         64bit
  15.162ms       8.927ms    divideImageDataWithParam
 266.646ms     294.134ms    divideImageDataWithParam_OpenMP single-threaded parallel=false  
 239.564ms    1195.556ms    divideImageDataWithParam_OpenMP multi-threaded parallel=true
```

Screenshot from Intel VTune Amplifier, where divideImageDataWithParam_OpenMP() with parallel=false take most of the time in instruction mov to dst memory.
[image: Intel VTune Amplifier]

Comment: 1) remember to build with compiler optimizations enabled. 2) OpenMP (or any kind of parallelizing) is not a silver bullet, there has to be enough parallel work available in your prog to negate the overhead of creating multiple threads, doing synchronization and more. Otherwise you are just slowing things down. 3) be aware of things like *priority inversions*, *false sharing*, *live locks*, *dead locks*, *race conditions*, *synchronization* and much, *much* more when attempting to parallelize code. There are *many* potential pitfalls. 4) different vendors OpenMP library perf also differs.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but how is it possible in this simply code with #pragma omp and if parallel set to false to get 20x more time (64bit) to process compare to code without pragma omp. It is littbe bit awkward for this simple task.

Comment: Did you find that ☆ __restrict dst made no difference? How about comparison of optimization reports with Intel compiler and comparing Intel and Microsoft omp libraries with msvc build?

Comment: With Intel omp library I can't imagine that omp_places=cores and reducing nthreads would not show interesting results.

Comment: Keyword __restrict dst made no difference and I placed results from Intel C++ Compiler and it is still slower than single thread without OpenMP and even slower with multi-threaded OpenMP. The function divideImageDataWithParam(param = 1) is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

648trindade is right; it has to do with optimizations that cannot be done with openmp. But its not loop-unrolling or vectorization, its inlining which allows for a smart substitution.

Let me explain: Integer divisions are incredibly slow (64bit `IDIV`: ~40-100 Cycles). So whenever possible people (and compilers) try to avoid divisions. One trick you can use is to substitute a division with a multiplication and a shift. That only works if the divisor is known at compile time. This is the case because your function `divideImageDataWithParam` is inlined and PARAM is known. You can verify this by prepending it with `__declspec(noinline)`. You will get the timings that you expected.

The openmp parallelization does not allow this trick because the function cannot be inlined and therefore `param` is not known at compile time and an expensive `IDIV`-instruction is generated.

Compiler output of `divideImageDataWithParam` (WIN10, MSVC2017, x64):

```
0x7ff67d151480  <+  336>         movzx   ecx,byte ptr [r10+r8]
0x7ff67d151485  <+  341>         mov     rax,r12
0x7ff67d151488  <+  344>         mul     rax,rcx                  <------- multiply
0x7ff67d15148b  <+  347>         shr     rdx,3                    <------- shift
0x7ff67d15148f  <+  351>         mov     byte ptr [r8],dl
0x7ff67d151492  <+  354>         lea     r8,[r8+1]
0x7ff67d151496  <+  358>         sub     r9,1
0x7ff67d15149a  <+  362>         jne     test!main+0x150 (00007ff6`7d151480)
```

And the openmp-version:

```
0x7ff67d151210  <+  192>         movzx   eax,byte ptr [r10+rcx]
0x7ff67d151215  <+  197>         lea     rcx,[rcx+1]
0x7ff67d151219  <+  201>         cqo
0x7ff67d15121b  <+  203>         idiv    rax,rbp                  <------- idiv
0x7ff67d15121e  <+  206>         mov     byte ptr [rcx-1],al
0x7ff67d151221  <+  209>         lea     rax,[r8+rcx]
0x7ff67d151225  <+  213>         mov     rdx,qword ptr [rbx]
0x7ff67d151228  <+  216>         cmp     rax,rdx
0x7ff67d15122b  <+  219>         jl      test!divideImageDataWithParam$omp$1+0xc0 (00007ff6`7d151210)
```

Note 1) If you try out the compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/) you will see that some compilers do the substitution for the openmp version too.

Note 2) As soon as the parameter is not known at compile time this optimization cannot be done anyway. So if you put your function into a library it will be slow. I'd do something like precomputing the division for all possible values and then do a lookup. This is even faster because the lookup table fits into 4-5 cache lines and L1 latency is only 3-4 cycles.

```
void divideImageDataWithParam(
    const unsigned char * src, int_t srcStep, unsigned char * dst, int_t dstStep, TSize size, int_t param)
{
    uint8_t tbl[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        tbl[i] = i / param;
    }

    for (int_t y = 0; y < size.height; y++)
    {
        for (int_t x = 0; x < size.width; x++)
        {
            dst[y*dstStep + x] = tbl[src[y*srcStep + x]];
        }
    }
}
```

Also thanks for the interesting question, I learned a thing or two along the way! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is explained by the use of compiler optimizations: when enabled, `divideImageDataWithParam` sequential code will be subjected to a series of optimizations (loop-unrolling, vectorization, etc.) that `divideImageDataWithParam_OpenMP` parallel code probably is not, as it is certainly *uncharacterized* after the process of **outlining parallel regions** by the compiler.

If you compile this same code without optimizations, you will find that the runtime version of the sequential version is **very similar** to that of the parallel version with only one thread.

The maximum speedup of parallel version in this case is limited by the division of the original workload without optimizations. Optimizations in this case need to be writed manually.

Comment: Also remember that in this case the use of a static loop scheduler (`schedule(static)`) can bring some performance improvement as the workload does not vary between iterations. By default, OpenMP runtimes often use the dynamic scheduler.